# Can I use Azure Mobile Services with Unity 3d ?

Tags: .net, azure, unity-game-engine

It seems Unity3d 4.3 requires the DLLs you create to be .NET 3.5 or lower. So does this mean I cannot use Azure Mobile Services? If not.. Are there any alternative ways to use Azure for a backend for a unity 3d game ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this open sourced plugin for Unity and Mobile Services:

https://github.com/bitrave/azure-mobile-services-for-unity3d

and

http://www.bitrave.com/azure-mobile-services-for-unity-3d/

Comment: Yes.. I saw that and thought I would work with it manually.. But it is looking like I should take another look at that

Comment: I've created a tutorial about how to get started with Unity and BitRave:   http://www.deadlyfingers.net/azure/unity3d-game-dev-with-azure-mobile-services-using-bitrave-plugin/